# Modern openGL how to change vertices value?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-3

My code is:

```
typedef Angel::vec4 color4;
color4 light_ambient( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 );
```

How to change the light_ambient value to `light_ambient( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );` during program run by press keyboard `q` key?

Comment: If this is modern GL, you should be using shaders. In which case, your shader should have a uniform to define ambient lighting. Look into [`glUniform4fv (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glUniform.xml) and [`glGetUniformLocation (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml). This is all speculation, because you have not included enough information to give a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Angel, but what you want is not exactly possible with this piece of code. You must change each element from vec4 manually.

Eg.

```
color.r = 1.0;
color.g = 1.0;
color.b = 1.0;
color.a = 1.0;
```

Comment: you still need to pass it to the relevant object buffer

Comment: that should be easy using glbuffersubdata: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml